# game.stackexchange(Arqade) for inside game questions or not?

Tags: discussion

How ever I have some kinda new to game.stackexchange and my question in here is what the scope of questions in this site? Is it for inside game problem or asking how I can pass this level in some game or I can ask questions about how can I install game or problem with Steam and so on? I looked at Arqade and find this topics should be asked :

- Gameplay strategies and tactics
- Puzzle solving or obstacle clearing
- Game mechanics and terminology
- Plot and characters in games
- Game-specific hardware and utilities

And in prohobit questions nothing said about out game questions and application realated to games like Steam .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly speaking, we cover both inside of game (how do I pass level X) as well as slightly outside of game (game Y crashes when I do this, how do I fix) questions. As @Robotnik mentioned in a comment, we also cover gaming consoles, peripherals, emulators and gaming related software, like steam.

You'll find more specific details in the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

You can also come by [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) and discuss the specific question you have.

Comment: We also cover gaming consoles (PS4/xbone and all the way down), gaming peripherals (controllers etc), emulators and gaming software (ePSXe, Steam etc)

Comment: People need rep to come into our chat. It doesnt look like he has an account here yet.

Comment: @James it requires SE-wide rep, not site specific rep to chat

Comment: Ahh, Good to know. i always thought the little chat thing wouldnt even show up on a site until that happened.

Answer (score 0):

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour

The tour of our community will show you all the topics we cover.

Comment: Looks like he's already seen that, because he seems to be quoting bits of that in the question. And the tour is good, but it doesn't cover every little variation in our rules, necessarily.